# Send file from FileProvider to another app

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to send file to another app for using Intent. I used `targetSdkVersion 25` in my gradle. My app works fine on android version < 24. When android version >= 24, i'm using `FileProvider` for sending file to another app and it's not working here.

This is step I using for `FileProvider`:

manifest:

```
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="sp.xxx.yyy.fileProvider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/file_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

file_paths:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths>
  <external-path path="Android/data/sp.xxx.yyy/" name="app_root" />

  <external-path path="Android/data/sp.xxx.yyy/files/" name="files_root" />

  <external-path path="." name="external_storage_root" />
</paths>
```

Open intent:

```
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
            File file = new File(path);
            Log.e("Utils" , "file exists: " + file.exists());
            Uri contentUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(context, "sp.xxx.yyy.fileProvider", file);
            intent.setData(contentUri);
        } else {
            Uri contentUri = Uri.parse(path);
            intent.setData(contentUri);
        }

        context.startActivity(intent);
```

When use `FileProvider` for sending file uri to another app, I see that other app receive data like this: 
`Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://sp.xxx.yyy.fileProvider/external_storage_root/Android/data/sp.xxx.yyy/files/filetosending.txt flg=0x10400002 cmp=sp.zzz/sp.zzz.MainActivity launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } }`

Another app not works with data received `content://sp.xxx.yyy.fileProvider/external_storage_root/Android/data/sp.xxx.yyy/files/filetosending.txt`

What's wrong in my code? Have any suggestion for resolve this problem? Thank your support.

Comment: `new File(path);`. Please tell the value of path.

Comment: Use `addFlags()`, not `setFlags()`. Your second `setFlags()` call removes the ability for the other app to read, because you replace your read permission with a write permission.

Comment: @greenapps the path is `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/sp.xxx.yyy/files/filetosending.txt`

Comment: @CommonsWave I have changed to `addFlags()`, but it still not work.

Comment: No. Not that way. You should set() one and add() the other. Or use set(flag1 l flag2).

Comment: @greenapps I have tried it but still not working.

Comment: Which error(s) do you get? You should give more info. You declare three <external-path>. Better remove the first two.

Comment: I removed. But data receive in other app wrong. It has received: `Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://sp.xxx.yyy.fileProvider/external_storage_root/Android/data/sp.xxx.yyy/files/filetosending.txt flg=0x10400002 cmp=sp.zzz/sp.zzz.MainActivity launchParam=MultiScreenLaunchParams { mDisplayId=0 mFlags=0 } }`

However, the uri sending is: `/storage/emulated/0/Android/data/sp.xxx.yyy/files/filetosend‌​ing.txt`

Comment: The data received in other app is perfect. Its a content scheme by your file provider for the mentioned path. You talk about uri sending but what follows is not the content scheme uri but a file path. Please tell which problems the receiving app encounters using the content scheme.

Comment: @PhanSinh Did you find a solution to your problem?  I am facing a similar issue...

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky oh not yet. I'm pending this function there.